# How to add Scroll to top in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am adding the Scroll to top div in Footer section. 
After clicking on the scroll top icon it will go the top of page

After Clicking on the Scroll to top it will go the top of page

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';

class ScrollTop extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="scrolltop">
                <i className="fa fa-angle-up" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ScrollTop;
```

Comment: React is just JavaScript. Not everything has to be done the "React way".

Answer (score 10):

Just use vanilla javascript

```
import React from 'react';

class ScrollTop extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="scrolltop" onClick={() => window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'})}>
                <i className="fa fa-angle-up" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ScrollTop;
```

Comment: The component is stateless, so a function component will do:
`function ScrollTop(){return(<div ... />)}`

Answer (score 2):

may be use this function

```
handleScroll=()=>{
    window.scrollX(0);
    // or 
    window.scroll({top:0,behavior:'smooth'})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install react-scroll from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll
2. Import and use in your component like below(ES6 style):

```js
import { Link, animateScroll as scroll } from "react-scroll";

<Link 
to="/" 
className='someDiv'
onClick={()=>scroll.scrollToTop()}>
Logo
</Link>
```

3. Click on the element(here Logo) to see the magic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before this code, you must install react-router.
2. `npm i react-router-dom`

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function scrollTop() {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, [pathname])

    return null;
}
```